# Python: Folium popup not working when rendering HTML

Tags: qgis, python, folium

I want to do HTML formatting into a folium map popup. When I try to render html by using `def format_popup_content(row)` function then the map does not display. How do I format popup?

This is what I have tried so far

```
def format_popup_content(row):
    # Format the popup content using HTML
    popup_content = f"""
    <div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center;">District: {row['district']}</h2>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Diagnose:</td>
                <td>{row['provisionaldiagnose']}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Age:</td>
                <td>{row['age']}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Gender:</td>
                <td>{row['pgender']}</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Add more information here if needed -->
        </table>
    </div>
    """
    return popup_content
```

This is the code of popup functionality

```
popup_text = folium.Html(format_popup_content(row), script=True) 
iframe = branca.element.IFrame(html=popup_text, width=320, height=500)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, parse_html=True)

# Update the color parameter to use the corresponding color from the color dictionary
folium.CircleMarker([lat, lon], radius=7, color=color, opacity=1.0, fill_color=color, popup=popup).add_to(district_layers[district])
```